# Directory structure for JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Going through some question and read this one

> Do I need to follow directory structure to run a simple JSP ?

what exactly is directory structure for JSP ?

and answer for

```
Do I need to follow directory structure to run a simple JSP ?
```

Answer (score 0):

> what exactly is directory structure for JSP ?

Just like we maintain a package structure for the java classes, we can maintain a directory or folder structure for jsp pages for better organization. Also if you want to access the jsps directly from the browser keep them outside WEB-INF folder.

[image]

> Do I need to follow directory structure to run a simple JSP ?

No, its not mandatory to follow a directory structure. You can dump all the jsps in one folder & run them.